# jQuery.parseJSON fails to parse serialised C# dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I am using [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/07/23/javascriptserializer-dictionary-to-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx) to serialise a C# dictionary.
The C# dictionary gets serialized to a string.
The `@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ElementDivIDs))` works like a charm. This is the output I get,:

```
  var jsonString = {"9":["ele9-tabs-attr9","ele9-tabs-attr48"],"10":["ele10-tabs-attr10"],"11":["ele11-tabs-attr11"],"12":["ele12-tabs-attr12","ele12-tabs-attr49"],"13":["ele13-tabs-attr13"],"14":["ele14-tabs-attr14"]}
```

I want to convert this into a Javascript associative array.
But the call to **jquery.parseJSON** returns NULL.

`var dictionaryOfOtherDivs  = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );`

`dictionaryOfOtherDivs` is null after this.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     var jsonString = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ElementDivIDs))
     console.log(jsonString); 
     var dictionaryOfOtherDivs  = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString ); 
     for(var dictKey in dictionaryOfOtherDivs)
     { 
        console.log("key = " + dictKey + ", value = " + dictionaryOfOtherDivs[dictKey]); 
     }
     //Do some more things
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a JSON string; that's an ordinary object literal.

You don't need to parse it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` returns a string and not an object literal. I tested just now, I could use a for-in loop to access the key and value, and also access a specify value using `jsonString[keyName]`

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.parseJSON` takes a *string* and outputs an *object*. However, you decided to inject the JSON itself right into the script, so the JavaScript engine will already have parsed it into an object literal, as if you'd have written that whole thing yourself as regular code.

Simply put, you already have a parsed object literal, you don't need to do any parsing anymore.

Comment: Thanks Mattias for the explanation. Accepted SLaks' answer because it was first.